# MySql multiple select from two tables and join their results to a third table

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have three tables: Players, PlayersArchive, Races. The Players and PlayersArchive tables are exactly the same structure.

In Players and PlayersArchive we have PlayerID and Name.

In Races we have in one row:

RaceID, Record1PlayerID, Record2PlayerID, Record3PlayerID, Record4PlayerID and Record5PlayerID

The task is to SELECT the whole Races table, but instead of the player ID fields it should return their names.

e.g.:

```
Races table:
RaceID: 1
Record1PlayerID: 2
Record2PlayerID: 1
Record3PlayerID: 0
Record4PlayerID: 0
Record5PlayerID: 0
```

---

```
Players table:
PlayerID: 1
Name: Jhon
```

---

```
PlayersArchive table:
PlayerID: 2
Name: Jack
```

---

```
result:
1     Jack     Jhon     NULL     NULL     NULL
```

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/sql-basics-query-multiple-tables/

Comment: you can achieve this with a left join and some googling

Comment: If players and playersArchive table are basically the same, why do you separate them?

Comment: (following on from what @fancyPants says..) Unless you're expecting **vast** amounts of data (and even then there are ways of scaling things - have you remembered to add indexes to the fields you're using in the join?), you're making things more complicated than they need to be by splitting players into a separate archive table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems with your data structure.  The first is that you should have a separate table for the players in each race, with one row per player/race combination.  Putting them in separate columns on a single row is a bad idea.

The second problem is putting the names in two different tables.  From your question, I cannot tell if both the `players` table and `playersarchive` table are necessary. So, I'll assume the archive is not necessary.

The solution is to join from the races table to the table with the players information:

```
select r.*,
       p1.name as name1,
       p2.name as name2,
       p3.name as name3,
       p4.name as name4,
       p5.name as name5
from races r left outer join
     players p1
     on r.record1playerid = p1.playerid left outer join
     players p2
     on r.record1playerid = p2.playerid left outer join
     players p3
     on r.record1playerid = p3.playerid left outer join
     players p4
     on r.record1playerid = p4.playerid left outer join
     players p5
     on r.record1playerid = p5.playerid left outer join
```

If the data is really in both `Players` and `PlayersArchive`, then `players` might need to be:

```
     (select distinct playerid, name from ((select p.* from players) union all (select pa.* from playersarchive)) t) p1 . . .
```

This combines the two tables together for looking up the name.

Answer (score 0):

This will only demonstrate a posible solution to what you ask.

```
Select RaceId, p1.Name AS Name1 From Races AS r
Left Join (
    Select * From Players 
    Union Select * From PlayersArchive
) AS p1 On r.Record1PlayerID = p1.PlayerID;
```

You should repeat this left join 4 more times whithin your query to get all 5 names.
Please note that with big data this might take a long time to execute.